# How to find hash on FRED graph API

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Has anyone figured out a way to get the unique hashes from the FRED (Federal Reserve Economic Data) graph API? What would be nice to do is to be able to use the graph API with some basic search engine (or just a select list of indicators no search engine) and quickly search over various economic indicators in a web app. That way you can just change the src for an iframe and get the same chart you would find on FRED. You could then pretty much develop a nice client side app and build on it to maybe provide a better user experience than FRED, which is good but could be better.

**Not trying to do this to create some paid service, as this would come at virtually no cost. I'm interested in it so I don't need to scrape all indicators and then request all observations for them... and then schedule that to update where applicable for each one. Which does currently come at a cost/compute time, which is also mostly irrelevant, but could be less load on FRED. I feel like they should make these hashes known for that reasoning.**

Using the T10Y2Y as an example:

When you first load the web page for the T10Y2Y requests are made to a few API's. There a few things you will notice

```
GET request
id = maps to the FRED codes we know
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/api/series/?id=T10Y2Y&width=718

POST request
sid = also maps to the FRED codes we know
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/api/series/?obs=true&sid=T10Y2Y
```

Now within the T10Y2Y there is an option to embed the graph to a widget, without using Selenium / some web driver. You can focus on and html id called embed-code, which should contain the embed code for the graph. However when you do so and try to copy the clipboard value the embed-code value returns "". So some JS is being executed when an actual user clicks on this to then populate the value to the embed URL... so this won't work, unless I'm missing something.

If we instead now look at the URL that the embed code provides to us we get the below information.

```
GET request
has hash ID in url as query parameter
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/api/series/?hash=18bSq&width=718&embed=true

POST request
has both hash and sid... we know sid so maybe this can help
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/api/series/?obs=true&sid=T10Y2Y&hash=18bSq&embed=true
```

Now looking at some of the payload information we start to notice that all of these requests include something called legacy_url which includes the hash for the graph. Unfortunately all of our requests made when we load the page scrub the hash part. Now if we try querying the embed widget's api like below with the known indicator value for sid, we're returned with an error.

```
GET request
https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/api/series/?sid=T10Y2Y
```

The payload for this request to work needs hash id and we can't know hash id without some API that maps to id or sid. All I can do is guess as the hash appears to be some random autoincrementing id that adds alpha characters for different versions of the same graph. If we mess with this even more (POST payload) we are even sent to a login for FRED.

Has anyone sniffed around enough to figure this out? I don't want to use selenium but it looks like it could be the only option... if it's even enough to trick the embed-code clipboard.. probably is.